# webrtc works in local network and but on remote network?

Tags: webrtc

I have created a quick video chat with webrtc and nodejs.

**Problem is : it works great on local network.
But not on remote network.**

Any clue where I should have a look ?

regards

Source code:

```
'use strict';
var sendChannel;

/////////////////////////////////////////////
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(target, replacement) {
  return this.split(target).join(replacement);
};

// template engine
String.prototype.format = function() {
  var args = arguments;
  return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) { 
    return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
      ? args[number]
      : match
    ;
  });
};
  function formatSeconds(time) {
    var mins = ~~(time / 60);
    var secs = time % 60;
    var mins = ~~((time % 3600) / 60);
    var secs = time % 60;

    var ret = "";
    ret += "" + mins + ":" + (secs < 10 ? "0" : "");
    ret += "" + secs;
    return ret;
  }




var isChannelReady;
var isInitiator = false;
var isStarted = false;
var localStream;
var remoteStream;
var pc;
var turnReady;
var audio = new Audio('assets/soundsdink.mp3');

var pc_config = {'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}]};
//var pc_config = {'iceServers': [{'url': 'stun.softjoys.com'}]};

var pc_constraints = {'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': true}, {'RtpDataChannels': true}]};

var localVideo = document.getElementById('localVideo');
var remoteVideo = document.getElementById('remoteVideo');

var constraints = {video: true, audio : true};
var timer;
var socket = io.connect();
var sdpConstraints = {'mandatory': {
  'OfferToReceiveAudio':true,
  'OfferToReceiveVideo':true }
};


getUserMedia(constraints, handleUserMedia, handleUserMediaError);
if (myuser.room !== '') {
  console.log('connect', myuser.room);
  socket.emit('connect', myuser);
}




function init() {
  $("#closeBtn").click(function() {
    location.reload();
  });
  $("#muteMicro").click(function() {
    toggleSound(localStream);
    if ($(this).data("checked")==0) {
      $(this).data("checked",1);
      $(this).css("background-image","url(../assets/images/micro_over.png)");
    } else {
      $(this).data("checked",0);
      $(this).css("background-image","url(../assets/images/micro.png)");
    }
  }) 
  $("#volumeBtn").click(function() {
    toggleSound(remoteStream);
    if ($(this).data("checked")==0) {
      $(this).data("checked",1);
      $(this).css("background-image","url(../assets/images/sound_over.png)");
    } else {
      $(this).data("checked",0);
      $(this).css("background-image","url(../assets/images/sound.png)");
    }
  })   



}

function toggleSound(stream) { // stream is your local WebRTC stream
  var audioTracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
  for (var i = 0, l = audioTracks.length; i < l; i++) {
    audioTracks[i].enabled = !audioTracks[i].enabled;
  }
}

// Set up audio and video regardless of what devices are present.

socket.on('requestChat', function (user){
  startCall();
});


socket.on('created', function (user){
  console.log('Created room ' + user.room);
  isInitiator = true;
});

socket.on('full', function (user){
  console.log('Room ' + user.room + ' is full');
});




socket.on('join', function (user){
  console.log('Another peer made a request to join room ' + user.room);
  console.log(user.username +" join");
  isChannelReady = true;

});

socket.on('joined', function (user){
  console.log('This peer has joined room ' + user.room);
  isChannelReady = true;  
});

socket.on('log', function (array){
  console.log.apply(console, array);
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////

function sendMessage(message){
    console.log('Client sending message: ', message);
  socket.emit('message', message, myuser);
}

socket.on('message', function (message, user){
  //console.log(message);
  if (user && user.username && myuser.username!=user.username && hisuser.username!=user.username) {
    hisuser = user;
    console.log("message  from:"+user.username);
    $("#spanUser").text(hisuser.username);
    $("#remoteVideo").show("slow");
    addUser(user);
  }


  if (message === 'got user media') {
    //startCall();
  } else if (message.type === 'offer') {
    if (!isInitiator && !isStarted) {
      startCall();
    }
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
    doAnswer();
  } else if (message.type === 'answer' && isStarted) {
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(message));
  } else if (message.type === 'candidate' && isStarted) {
    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
      sdpMLineIndex: message.label,
      candidate: message.candidate
    });
    pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
  } else if (message === 'bye') {
    endChat(user);
  }
});
function endChat(user) {
  if (isStarted) {
    isStarted = false;
    pc.close();
    pc = null;    
  }  
  hisuser = {};
  console.log('connection closed');
  $("#remoteVideo").hide("slow");
  $("#spanUser").text("");
  $("#spanTimer").text("");
  removeUser(user);
}

function removeUser(user) {
  $("#item_"+user.username).remove();
  delete users[user.username]; 
  clearInterval(timer)

}
function addUser(user) {

  users[user.username] = user;
  //alert("addUser");
  if (myuser.mode!="A") {
      socket.emit('requestChat', myuser);
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////



function handleUserMedia(stream) {
  console.log('Adding local stream.');
  localVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
  localStream = stream;
  sendMessage('got user media');
  $("#localVideo").show("slow");
  if (isInitiator) {
    //startCall();
  }
}

function handleUserMediaError(error){
  console.log('getUserMedia error: ', error);
}


  function updateTimer() {
    myuser.seconds++;
    $("#spanTimer").text("Time:"+formatSeconds(myuser.seconds));
  }


function startCall() {
  myuser.seconds = 0;
  if (!isStarted && typeof localStream != 'undefined' && isChannelReady) {
    createPeerConnection();
    pc.addStream(localStream);
    isStarted = true;
    console.log('isInitiator', isInitiator);
    if (isInitiator) {
      pc.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, handleCreateOfferError);
    }
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(updateTimer,1000);
  }
}
function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
  // Set Opus as the preferred codec in SDP if Opus is present.
  sessionDescription.sdp = preferOpus(sessionDescription.sdp);
  pc.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
  console.log('setLocalAndSendMessage sending message' , sessionDescription);
  sendMessage(sessionDescription);
}
function doAnswer() {
  console.log('Sending answer to peer.');
  pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, logError, sdpConstraints);
  //pc.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage);
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function createPeerConnection() {
  try {
    pc = new RTCPeerConnection(null, pc_constraints);
    pc.onicecandidate = handleIceCandidate;
    pc.onaddstream = handleRemoteStreamAdded;
    pc.onremovestream = handleRemoteStreamRemoved;
    console.log('Created RTCPeerConnnection');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Failed to create PeerConnection, exception: ' + e.message);
    alert('Cannot create RTCPeerConnection object.');
      return;
  }


}

function handleIceCandidate(event) {
  console.log('handleIceCandidate event: ', event);
  if (event.candidate) {
    sendMessage({
      type: 'candidate',
      label: event.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
      id: event.candidate.sdpMid,
      candidate: event.candidate.candidate});
  } else {
    console.log('End of candidates.');
  }
}

function handleRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream added.');
  remoteVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
  remoteStream = event.stream;

}

function handleCreateOfferError(event){
  console.log('createOffer() error: ', e);
}



function logError(error) {
    console.log(error.name + ": " + error.message);
}


function requestTurn(turn_url) {
  var turnExists = false;
  for (var i in pc_config.iceServers) {
    if (pc_config.iceServers[i].url.substr(0, 5) === 'turn:') {
      turnExists = true;
      turnReady = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (!turnExists) {
    console.log('Getting TURN server from ', turn_url);
    // No TURN server. Get one from computeengineondemand.appspot.com:
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var turnServer = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log('Got TURN server: ', turnServer);
        pc_config.iceServers.push({
          'url': 'turn:' + turnServer.username + '@' + turnServer.turn,
          'credential': turnServer.password
        });
        turnReady = true;
      }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', turn_url, true);
    xhr.send();
  }
}

function handleRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
  console.log('Remote stream removed. Event: ', event);
}




///////////////////////////////////////////

// Set Opus as the default audio codec if it's present.
function preferOpus(sdp) {
  var sdpLines = sdp.split('\r\n');
  var mLineIndex;
  // Search for m line.
  for (var i = 0; i < sdpLines.length; i++) {
      if (sdpLines[i].search('m=audio') !== -1) {
        mLineIndex = i;
        break;
      }
  }
  if (mLineIndex === null) {
    return sdp;
  }

  // If Opus is available, set it as the default in m line.
  for (i = 0; i < sdpLines.length; i++) {
    if (sdpLines[i].search('opus/48000') !== -1) {
      var opusPayload = extractSdp(sdpLines[i], /:(\d+) opus\/48000/i);
      if (opusPayload) {
        sdpLines[mLineIndex] = setDefaultCodec(sdpLines[mLineIndex], opusPayload);
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  // Remove CN in m line and sdp.
  sdpLines = removeCN(sdpLines, mLineIndex);

  sdp = sdpLines.join('\r\n');
  return sdp;
}

function extractSdp(sdpLine, pattern) {
  var result = sdpLine.match(pattern);
  return result && result.length === 2 ? result[1] : null;
}

// Set the selected codec to the first in m line.
function setDefaultCodec(mLine, payload) {
  var elements = mLine.split(' ');
  var newLine = [];
  var index = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (index === 3) { // Format of media starts from the fourth.
      newLine[index++] = payload; // Put target payload to the first.
    }
    if (elements[i] !== payload) {
      newLine[index++] = elements[i];
    }
  }
  return newLine.join(' ');
}

// Strip CN from sdp before CN constraints is ready.
function removeCN(sdpLines, mLineIndex) {
  var mLineElements = sdpLines[mLineIndex].split(' ');
  // Scan from end for the convenience of removing an item.
  for (var i = sdpLines.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var payload = extractSdp(sdpLines[i], /a=rtpmap:(\d+) CN\/\d+/i);
    if (payload) {
      var cnPos = mLineElements.indexOf(payload);
      if (cnPos !== -1) {
        // Remove CN payload from m line.
        mLineElements.splice(cnPos, 1);
      }
      // Remove CN line in sdp
      sdpLines.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }

  sdpLines[mLineIndex] = mLineElements.join(' ');
  return sdpLines;
}
```

This question is very similar to : [Error with WebRTC video stream between two different network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159455/error-with-webrtc-video-stream-between-two-different-network)

I think it's the same problem, but I could not solve that.

Comment: you'll need to show your code

Comment: what do you mean by remote network?

Answer (score 3):

80% of the time you will not need a TURN server(I do not know of an open TURN server that is available due to their bandwidth requirements) but, I would suggest trying one to make sure that is not your issue. You are currently not using ANY Turn server in your code from what I can see.

Also, you should store the IceCandidates that you get before getting the remote SDP instead of just discarding them as you are currently, and add them all once you get the SDP set.

EDIT:

IceCandidates are possible connection points that a peerconnection gets when having a dialog with the an ICE server(STUN or TURN).

For client A to get client B's candidates, you have to make them available via a signalling server. You are already doing this, but you are ignoring all of them until you get client B's offer. You should instead, put these candidates in an array and then add them after the offer is grabbed.

However, you can skip all the ICE-trickling logic by not sending the offer nor the reply until all the respective ice gathering is complete(the peerconnection's `icegatheringstatus` is set to `complete`).

Also, as TURN goes, it is needed when there are certain types of firewalls and Symmetric NATs. So, if you have a network firewall or a symmetric NAT on EITHER side of the connection, a STUN server will not suffice.

There is a free TURN server solution that you can put on a free amazon EC2 instance. Some setup would be required but you would then have a turn server without having to pay anything. [Link to image documentation](https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/source/browse/amazonlinuxami/turnserver-3.1.2.1-amazon-aws-ec2-x86_64.txt?spec=svn1019&r=1019)

Comment: Thansk for your answer.
Can you give me more details ? or more clues ?
Regards

Answer (score 1):

here are some steps to help you debug this:

- test your connection/ports on both sides with http://www.netscan.co
- This is an obvious modification of appRTC to work with socket.io. This is not the latest version, you might want to update it.
- remove the XHR fetching of TURN server, as your application will not get a turn server from google infrastructure (as the origin is not appRTC.appspot.com). It will make your code clearer.
- check the list of generated ice candidates on both sides, to be sure there are some "srflx" candidates. Otherwise, you have a problem with your turn server. Note: the server you use does not work with firefox for example. The latest source code of appRTC will tell yo what to use.
- Check that your ice servers are correctly formatted (note: firefox does not follow the specs yet w.r.t. url/urls, again, check appRTC for reference).
- Get a free test TURN server (http://numb.viagenie.ca)